# This form of use of printf api makes it safer?

Tags: c, api, buffer-overflow

```
char str[] = "some text";

printf ( "%.*s", strlen(str), str );
```

** Of course, their buffers, strings yet to be properly targeted

Comment: What attack are you trying to prevent?

Answer (score 3):

No, that just shifts the problem of detecting the end of the string from printf to strlen, and it's still exactly the same.

Comment: printf does not attempt to detect the end of the buffer.

Comment: @Billy: printf attempts to detect the end of the string (the logical value, not the end of the buffer) by looking for a null character.

Comment: @Roger Pate: Sorry .. was thinking sprintf :)

Answer (score 1):

No, printf should be safe form overruns anyway setting a field width doesn't really help

Answer (score 1):

In the example you give, there's no difference.  printf interprets the undecorated "%s" character code as meaning "read and print all characters from a character pointer until a null character is encountered."  The initializer `char str[] = "some text";` automatically appends the null character, so there will be no overrun.  On the other hand, the following is not safe

```
char str[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
printf("%s", str);
```

because no null character is appended to the character sequence `str`.  On the other hand, since `strlen(str)` determines string length by counting the number of characters before a null is encountered, it doesn't offer you any benefit over just using `printf` without a field width specified.

The upshot: the only case where specifying a field width for a string is helpful is when the string isn't guaranteed to be null-terminated (or the classic case of using `sprintf` to write to a buffer that may not be big enough to hold the contents of `str`), but in that case you'd have to determine string length using something other than `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's no different than:

```
char str[] = "some text";
printf("%s", str);
```